# how to set setOnClickListener for more than 1 spinner

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener

> Actually i got a value in server to create the spinner. i tried to set setOnClickListener for all spinners but it getting error.Refer my code below.

```
public static Spinner[] clickspin = new Spinner[nvalue];//nvalue = 2 (get from server)
for(int i=0;i<nvalue;i++)
{
clickspin[i]=new Spinner(this);
        clickspin[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(90/*length of combo box*/, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        clickspin[i].setAdapter(adapter1);
        clickspin[i].setId(i);
        clickspin[i].setClickable(true);
        clickspin[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {               
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                int n = v.getId();

            }
        });
}
```

> how to set setOnClickListener for every spinner

Comment: actually in logcat having a lot of lines . how to find exact error in logcat

Comment: Find the exact logcat by TAG.

Comment: paste your red line which are error.

Comment: without additional information I would guess that either adapter1 or nvalue are null, or `this` is not a valid Context

Comment: You want to use `onClickListener` or `onItemSelectedListener`

Comment: thanks for all if i use onItemSelectedListener instead onClickListener it will work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Spinners, we use [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

```
clickspin[i].OnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {               

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
    }
});
```

See the [Spinners guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

Comment: Is that `clickspin[i].setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()` or `clickspin[i].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()`?

Comment: no probs,, i corrected the error.i use setOnItemClickListener and it work properly

Answer (score 1):

implements `onClickListener` in to your Activity...
If u want to provide different functionality in each item..then also implement `onItemSelectedListener`